# Size of the uploaded image using multipart form data in Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data, multifile-uploader

Not able to get the size of the uploaded image using the multipart form data in web api C#.

I have used the code provided on the following website:
https://yogeshdotnet.com/web-api-2-file-upload-asp-net-mvc/

```
dataitem.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName
"\"TEST.png\""
dataitem.Headers.ContentDisposition.Size
null
dataitem.Headers.ContentDisposition
{form-data; name="test_image"; filename="TEST.png"}
    CreationDate: null
    DispositionType: "form-data"
    FileName: "\"TEST.png\""
    FileNameStar: null
    ModificationDate: null
    Name: "\"test_image\""
    Parameters: Count = 2
    ReadDate: null
    Size: null
```

size is null here. I want the size of the image. I ran this code in the immediate window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["test_image"];
//size of the image in bytes.
int size = file.ContentLength;
```

This helped me to get the size of the image.